# Leaflet offline grid layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want leaflet to work offline, without title, to show only a grid as titles. To have all the features of Leaflet, add plugins to draw a line, pin a marker, draw a polygon, zoom in / zoom out on shapes etc.

Is there a simple way to show just a simple grid?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a custom `GridLayer` (that's already been implemented by the Leaflet authors).  All you have to do is copy `L.GridLayer.DebugCoords` where you would normally load a tile layer.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0
});

L.GridLayer.DebugCoords = L.GridLayer.extend({
    createTile: function (coords, done) {
        var tile = document.createElement('div');
        //this adds tile coordinates; you may or may not want this
        tile.innerHTML = [coords.x, coords.y, coords.z].join(', ');
        tile.style.outline = '1px solid red';

        /* // you don't need this artificial timeout for your application
        setTimeout(function () {
                done(null, tile);   // Syntax is 'done(error, tile)'
        }, 500 + Math.random() * 1500);
        */

        return tile;
    }
});

L.gridLayer.debugCoords = function(opts) {
    return new L.GridLayer.DebugCoords(opts);
};

map.addLayer( L.gridLayer.debugCoords() );
```

Stand-alone, working example: http://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/gridcoords.html

Code taken from: http://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html